# Account setup for use with REST API - signature or certificate credential option?

Tags: api, rest, paypal, oauth-2.0, credentials

My boss is setting up a UK PayPal account for use with REST API for direct credit card payments and payouts.

During this process he's been asked to choose between signature and certificate credentials.

However as far as I understand the REST API uses OAuth 2.0 so what we need is an ID and secret associated to an App.

How should we proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up your credentials for REST is done on the developer site https://developer.paypal.com/. You are correct that the choice between "Signature" and "Certificate" is irrelevant in this case. Try the following:

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com and log in using the email address and password of the live PayPal account that will be receiving payments.
2. Click on “Dashboard” up at the top of the page. You should see a list of your apps here. (If, instead, you see a sentence that says “Create your first app to view it here”, you will need to create at least 1 app)
3. Click the app name. You’ll see your client ID and Secret for the Sandbox. Toggle your view to “Live” in the upper right corner of the page to see the credentials for the live environment.
4. You can click on “Account Eligibility” to see what features are available for Live. If the feature isn’t already added there will be an “Enable” link to the right. Clicking on the link will start the request process for that feature.